# When will $f\simeq g$ implies $X\bigsqcup_f Y\simeq X\bigsqcup_g Y$?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two topological spaces and $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ be two homotopic continuous map between them. My question is when will we have the attaching result space $X\bigsqcup_f Y$ and $X\bigsqcup_g Y$ are homotopic? Well, intuitively, $f,g$ give the way of attaching, and if $f\simeq g$, then we can think the attaching way determined by $f$ can be transformed continuously to the attaching wat determined by $g$, and hence the resulting attaching space should be homotopy. But I doubt this result is not true in general, otherwise this should be proved explicitly in standard textbooks of algebraic topology. So my question is when will the above true? Well, by asking this, I'm not going to pursue the most general result, I want some special cases and a justification why my intuition above failed in general. Thanks.

Aside: the reason I came up with this question is because I want to find the relation between homotopy of continuous maps and the homotopy of spaces, more explictly, I want to know is there any sense in which homotopy maps induce homotopy spaces?

Comment: An example to ponder. Let $E$ be the Hawaiian Earring space. Let $e_0$ be the natural basepoint where all the circles intersect. Let $e_1$ be some other choice of basepoint on one of the circles. Now consider two possible ways of gluing a copy of $E$ to another copy. Glue $e_0$ to $e_0$, or glue $e_0$ to $e_1$. These are not homotopy equivalent spaces, even though there is a homotopy of the attaching maps.

Comment: Does your notation mean what it looks like it means? Namely $X \sqcup_f Y$ is the quotient of the disjoint union $X \sqcup Y$ where each $x \in X$ is identified with $f(x) \in Y$? If so, then $X \sqcup_f Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y$, no matter what $f$ is: the induced function $Y \to X \sqcup_f Y$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Concerning Lee Mosher's comment see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_space .

Comment: For spaces you should say "homotopy equivalent" instead of "homotopic".

Answer (score 1):

Like Lee Mosher said in his comment: the space $X \sqcup_f Y$ will always be homeomorphic to $Y$. However if you let $f:A \rightarrow Y$ and $A \rightarrow X$ be a subspace inclusion we can ask the same question! If $f,g:A \rightarrow Y$ are two homotopic functions is it true that $X \sqcup_f Y \simeq X \sqcup_g Y$?

It turns out that the answer is yes if $A \rightarrow X$ is a *cofibration* (essentially a nice inclusion map). In particular all subcomplex inclusions $A \rightarrow X$ of $CW$ complexes are cofibrations.

For example, the map $S^{n-1} \rightarrow D^n$ is a cofibration.

This result can be proven with the help of *homotopy colimits* and model categories.

If you want to learn more about cofibrations and homotopy colimits I recommend reading the relevant parts of Jeffrey Stroms *Modern classical homotopy theory*.

Comment: I feel this is putting the cart before the horse. Verifying the axioms of a model category, and then building up the theory of homotopy colimits, and then showing that pushouts of cofibrations are homotopy pushouts – this is surely more laborious than working directly with the topological spaces and maps at hand; not to mention the loss of graphical intuition!

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I want to ask, surely I need to take subspace of $X$, otherwise things will gonna be trivial. I haven't touched the concept of cofiberation before, but having had just read the definition given by Wikipedia, I'm thinking is that equivalent to say the pair $(X,A)$ has homotopy extension property which is defined by A.Hatcher in his book?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right! @GK1202

Comment: Perhaps, but it's the way I learnt it and would prefer to be taught if I were to go back in time. Maybe it's because I have a knack for category theory... @ZhenLin

Comment: You’re talking to a (formerly professional) category theorist here – I think I have as much a knack for category theory as anyone around here. You should be more wary of abstract nonsense arguments, especially when they involve preconditions and lots of theory: you never know when you might end up making a circular argument.

Comment: Maybe you're not aware of the way Jeffrey Strom defines homotopy colimits. Perhaps you can actually read his book that I recommended before criticizing the method of teaching. @ZhenLin

Comment: At the risk of agreeing with Zhen Lin, maybe your answer would feel more complete if you explained why the answer should be yes when $A\rightarrow X$ is a cofibration.

Comment: It's difficult to explain without using abstract nonsense for me. @Tyrone

Comment: I don't have any objection to abstract nonsense.